# turning this trainwreck of a function into a recursive one

Tags: php, function, methods

I've been trying to build this recursive function for the better part of a day now, but I just can't seem to get it to work the way I want.

First, I have a property which holds some data that the function have to access:

```
$this->data
```

And then I have this string which the intention is to turn into a relative path:

```
$path = 'path.to.%id%-%folder%.containing.%info%';
```

The part of the string that are like this: %value% will load some dynamic values found in the `$this->data property` (like so: `$this->data['id'];` or `$this->data['folder'];`

and to make things really interesting, the property can reference itself again like so: `$this->data['folder'] = 'foldername.%subfolder%';` and also have two %values% separated by a - that would have to be left alone.

So to the problem, I've been trying to make a recursive function that will load the dynamic values from the data property, and then again if the new value contains another %value% and so on until no more %value%'s are loaded.

So far, this is what I've been able to come up with:

```
    public function recursiveFolder( $folder, $pathArr = null )
    {
        $newPathArr = explode( '.', $folder );
        if ( count ( $newPathArr ) !== 1 )
        {
            foreach( $newPathArr as $id => $folder )
            {
                $value = $this->recursiveFolder( $folder, $newPathArr );
                $resultArr = explode( '.', $value );
                if ( count ( $resultArr ) !== 1 )
                {
                    foreach ( $resultArr as $nid => $result )
                    {
                        $nvalue = $this->recursiveFolder( $result, $newPathArr );
                        $resultArr[$nid] = $nvalue;
                    }

                }
                $resultArr = implode( '.',$resultArr );
                $newPathArr[$id] = $resultArr;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $pattern = '/%(.*?)%/si';
            preg_match_all( $pattern, $folder, $matches );
            if ( empty( $matches[0] ) )
            {
                return $folder;
            }
            foreach ( $matches[1] as $mid => $match )
            {
                if ( isset( $this->data[$match] ) && $this->data[$match] != '' )
                {
                    $folder = str_replace( $matches[0][$mid], $this->data[$match], $folder );
                    return $folder;
                }
            }
        }

        return $newPathArr;
    }
```

Unfortunately it is not a recursive function at all as it grinds to a halt when it has multiple layers of %values%, but works with two layers -barely-. (I just coded it so that it would work at a bare minimalistic level this point).

Here's how it should work:

It should turn:

```
'files.%folder%.blog-%type%.and.%time%'
```

into:

```
'files.foldername.blog-post.and.2013.feb-12th.09'
```

based on this:

```
$data['folder'] = 'foldername';
$data['type']   = 'post';
$data['time']   = '%year%.%month%-%day%';
$data['year']   = 2013;
$data['month']  = 'feb';
$data['day']    = '12th.%hour%';
$data['hour']   = '09';
```

Hope you can help!
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for this too be solved recursively:

```
<?php
function putData($str, $data)
{
    // Repeat the replacing process until no more matches are found:
    while (preg_match("/%(.*?)%/si", $str, $matches))
    {
        // Use $matches to make your replaces
    }
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe, but how would this fare if the value is replaced with a new value containing another %%? like %time% would turn into %year%.%month%-%day% which again would turn into: 2013.feb-12th.%hour% which would finally turn into: 2013.feb-12th.09. (using the example at the bottom of my question). this is the reason I was going for a recursive function, but its been a long day, I may be missing something.

Comment: With my approach first `%time%` would turn into `%year%.%month%-%day%`, and after that `preg_match("/%(.*?)%/si", $str, $matches)` would be true, because there are new values to be replaced, so it executes the loop again. This goes on until all `%thing%`'s have been replaced.

Comment: does indeed work like a charm! don't I feel silly for going overboard! can't thank you enough for this solution!